# Como inicializar API Spotify no Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[Link do projeto no GitHub da API Spotify](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify)

Como inicializar esse projeto no Rails? normal seria "rails server", porém está faltando alguns arquivos do projeto padrão do Rails e está dando erro...

```
Description:
The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
defaults values shown above in this help message.
```

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

```
This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

Comment: Isso é uma Gem. Uma biblioteca em Rails para vc utilizar no seu próprio projeto. Não é um projeto para vc inicializar

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora tudo faz sentido kkk.

Comment: Só uma correção, conforme escrevi na resposta. Esta gem é para ruby, mas pode ser utilizada com o rails

Answer (score 0):

Esta é uma Gem ruby, uma pacote ruby que pode ser uma aplicação ou biblioteca. 
Neste caso, ele é uma biblioteca que encapsula a lógica de chamadas `a API do Spotify, para que não seja necessário vc desenvolver a sua própria.

Portanto, ele não deve ser inicializado com `rails new`.

Para utilizá-la vc deve adicioná-la ao seu próprio projeto, podendo ser uma aplicação rails ou apenas um arquivo .rb.

A partir disso utilizar os métodos disponíveis na documentação da API, que ensinam a buscar música, álbum, e etc.